# slick slider as custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I made HTML/CSS design of a web site, and now I need to convert it to WordPress. The part that I am working on right now is Adding slick slider to show only on my WP front page. It works perfectly in HTML (because there I incorporated javascript which could be found on actual slick slider website and initiated through 3 div elements with images inside.).

In WP functions.php I added:

```
   //Add slider

   add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );

   function create_post_type() {
      register_post_type( 'slider',
         array(
               'labels' => array(
               'name' => __( 'Sliders' ),
               'singular_name' => __( 'Slider' ),
               'add_new' => 'Add new slide',
       ),
               'public' => true,

      )
     );
}

?>
```

I also enqueued scripts and styles like this (in functions.php also):

```
 //Enqueue scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_all_scripts', 999);

function wp_enqueue_all_scripts(){

//add slick slider
wp_register_style('slickcss', get_template_directory_uri()."/slick/slick.css" );
wp_register_style('slickcsstheme', get_template_directory_uri()."/slick/slick-theme.css" );

//load slick js
wp_register_script('slickslider', get_template_directory_uri()."/slick/slick.min.js", array(jquery), '', true );

////load slick initiate script
wp_register_script( 'slickinit', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick-init.js');

// load slick on homepage
if ( is_front_page() ) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcss' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcsstheme' );
wp_enqueue_script ('slickslider');
wp_enqueue_script ('slickinit');
}
}
```

I added slick.init in js folder and it looks like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.featured-image-slider').slick({ //add CSS class of target
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    })
});
```

I made front-page.php and I put the code in there like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'slider' ),
);

// The Query
$query_slider = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="home regular slider">';
    while ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
        $query_slider->the_post();
        echo '<div> ';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>

<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

When I go to Sliders -> Add new slide in my dashboard, the slide is not showing on my front page. I am going out of my mind and would really appreciate help. How do I resolve this, what am I doing wrong? I am a total newbie and for the life of me I can not resolve it myself. Thank you.

Comment: are you getting the custom post type to show on the page (title, image, etc) - regardless of slickslider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you've written `array(jquery)` instead of `array('jquery')`. And also has not defined the `slickinit` enqueue position. So the right code will be-

```
 //Enqueue scripts
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_all_scripts', 999);

function wp_enqueue_all_scripts(){

    //add slick slider
    wp_register_style('slickcss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.css' );
    wp_register_style('slickcsstheme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick-theme.css' );

    //load slick js
    wp_register_script('slickslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    ////load slick initiate script
    wp_register_script( 'slickinit', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick-init.js',  array( 'jquery', 'slickslider' ) );

    // load slick on homepage
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcss' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcsstheme' );
        wp_enqueue_script ('slickslider');
        wp_enqueue_script ('slickinit');
    }
}
```

And at your `front-page.php` try this-

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php

// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'slider' ),
);

// The Query
$query_slider = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<div class="home regular slider">';
    while ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) {
        $query_slider->the_post();
        echo '<div class="featured-image-slider"> ';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>

<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

Hope that thing will be working now.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited the code as you suggested, but still it doesn't work...Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well in your `slickslider` initialize code you used `.featured-image-slider` class. But in your `front-page.php` I don't see any div or image with that class. So I think you `slickslider` is not being able to track your image.

Comment: Check updated answer... ! @Nancy

Comment: It works now. I do not know how to thank you enough! You have saved me and I learnt a lot with your help!

Comment: Well, that good news. Now if you accept the answer it would be great. @Nancy

Comment: I just did, but because of my low reputation, it doesn't show. So I am told. @the_dramatist

Comment: Look there is right sign below vote sign, click there. As far I know you can't vote. But still you can accept your questions answer.

Comment: Ok, done! Sorry for my ignorance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of WordPress plugin [Slick Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slick-slider/). It turns native WordPress galleries (`[gallery ids="x,y,z"]`) into sliders utilizing the great [slick slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) written by Ken Wheeler (which you also implement).

Using the plugin you wouldn't have to use custom post types.
Give it a try.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, @Philipp Bammes. I already managed to resolve the issue without using any plugins. Thanx, anyway.

Comment: Maybe it helps other people facing similar problems.