# Custom Post Type Slick Slider "$ is not a function"

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a slider with my custom post type `rt_testimonial`.  I believed I had everything setup but I'm getting an error in console:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

Here's what I did:

In my mu-plugins folder in a my_functions.php I created a post type `rt_testimonial`.  (this part is working)

In my mu-plugins folder in a my_functions.php I created a short code to call my posts:

```
add_shortcode('fellowship-testimonials', 'rt_show_testimonials');
function rt_show_testimonials() {
  $testimonialQuery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'rt_testimonial',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC'
  ));
  if ($testimonialQuery->have_posts()) {
    $testimonials = '<div class="testimonial-slider">';
    while($testimonialQuery->have_posts()){
      $testimonialQuery->the_post();
      $testimonials .= '<div class="featured-image-slider testimonial-item">
                <div class="testimonial-caption">'.get_the_content().'</div>
                <div class="testimonial-author">'.get_the_title().'</div>
               </div>';
    }
    $testimonials .= '</div>';

  } else { 
    $testimonials = 'no posts';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  return $testimonials;
}
```

In my child theme folder I added the slick directory (which I downloaded from here:  https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

`meetheme/slick/`  all the slick files are here.

Then I made a slick-init.js file in that same directory and put this in it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.testimonial-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
  });
});
```

Lastly in my child theme functions.php I put this to enqueue my scripts:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_slick_scripts', 999);

function wp_enqueue_slick_scripts(){

    //add slick slider
    wp_register_style('slickcss', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.css' );
    wp_register_style('slickcsstheme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick-theme.css' );

    //load slick js
    wp_register_script('slickslider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    ////load slick initiate script
    wp_register_script( 'slickinit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/slick/slick-init.js',  array( 'jquery', 'slickslider' ) );

    // load slick on homepage
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcss' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'slickcsstheme' );
        wp_enqueue_script ('slickslider');
        wp_enqueue_script ('slickinit');
    }
}
```

When I load the page with my shortcode I expect the slider, but I get all posts loading one under another.  In my console I get the error `TypeError: $ is not a function`

What did I do wrong here?

I based this off the slick site and this stack page: [slick slider as custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236400/slick-slider-as-custom-post-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `$` instead of `jQuery` you can wrap your JS code like this...

```
(function ($) {
    ...you js code
})(jQuery);
```

or use noConflict() by putting this at the top of your JS...

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Of course you could also replace all the `$` with `jQuery`.

Any of these will get rid of your error.

Comment: I added the second line you did and it worked.  Is there one that is "better" than the other?  I saw I could try `jQuery(function($)` too

Comment: Glad you got it.  I usually use the anonymous function (first code) but I think that's just a preference. I can't say that one is better than the others from a performance stand-point.